# How to get the List of Facebook Applications for a user using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can i get the list of applications created by the User. I would like to fetch this list using the Facebook Graph API. Could you please advice on which API on the Facebook Graph API to use and how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `/me/accounts`. I believe what you are looking or is at that endpoint.

Description of the endpoint -

> The Facebook apps and pages owned by the current user.

Permissions needed -

> `manage_pages` yields access_tokens that can be used to query the Graph API on behalf of the app/page

Take a look at the [user endpoint documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), there will be more information there.

Remember that ownership of an application doesn't necessarily mean that it was that user who created it, it just means that the user is an administrator of the application.

Comment: I believe this is no longer correct. When I try this the response contains only the pages accounts, not any app accounts.

Comment: @jezpez - I think its still the same endpoint but the permissions have changed slightly in the past 6 years ;) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-manage_pages

Comment: I believe that you now need to have your app reviewed in order to actually use this permission - perhaps that is what you are facing?

Comment: I have the manage_pages permission in the token used but the response does not contain apps. Our app shouldn't have to be reviewed if the app is in developer mode and we are admins of the app (otherwise how would anyone build a feature using this capability). From what I've read elsewhere it's no longer possible to retrieve the apps installed by a user from and FB api. I would love to be proved wrong but I think the only option is to ask users of our product to enter their facebook app Id manually.